# logstash won’t read single line files

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-file

I'm trying to make a pipeline that sends xml documents to elasticsearch. Problem is that each document is in its own separate file as a single line without \n in the end.

Any way to tell logstash not to wait for \n but read whole file till EOF and send it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you specify which logstash version you are using, and can you share your configuration?

It may depends on the mode you set: it may be tail or read. it defaults to tail, which means it listens on your file and it waits for default 1 hour before closing it and stopping waiting for new lines.

You may have to change this parameter fro 1 hour to 1 second if you know you have reached the EOF yet:

```
 file {
    close_older=> "1 second"
  }
```

Let me know if that works!

Docs here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-close_older